# Sending mass emails in Salesforce using SendGrid or MailChimp

Tags: email, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

I am working on Salesforce App where there is a custom object named Distributor (Distributor__c). A distributor has primary email address as one of the fields. When a new distributor record is added an email is suppose to go out welcoming them to the service with some other information (So on a bulk insert using dataloader, mass emails would be sent). Similarly, the user can send mass email notification to all the distributors (using a custom vf page and UI).

My problem is, I cannot use Salesforce's Messaging.MassEmailMessage since it wont work with custom objects and custom email templates. Neither can I use SingleEmailMessage since even if I put all the distributor email addresses in a list and email them, they can all see each others email addresses which is something the client does not want.

What I am looking for is a single email service that can also handle bulk. I came across [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com) and [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) which provide mass email services. I would like your opinion on which one is better and can work smoothly with Salesforce. Or if there is another native solution without using these third party email service providers.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can 'mass send' with SingleEmailMessage - just use BCC instead of To/CC.  to hide the other recipients email addresses.

Comment: If you reach the limit of ~25 email addresses then break the recipients up into chunks and loop around each chunk.

Comment: That is a good idea. The approx number of recipients is from 800 - 2500. However, since the email can be tailored for an individual distributor (like Hey Richard, or Hey John) I would either need to send one email to each distributor or completely remove the name or other individual info from the email.

Comment: and why doesn't normal process builder/workflow email alerts work?

Comment: I need to send somewhere between 800-2000 emails with custom content meant for each recipient. Forget the custom content, just the email volume is too large. I do not know if process builder or workflow emails will do the job. I might be wrong and thats what I need to know.

Comment: @codeinprogress I am into a similar situation, where I need to send mass emails, but in SF community cloud application. Currently the system uses GSuite service to send email which I need to stop this happening and use an alternative solution. Were you able to get a working solution? Pls share. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking into comparison chart for Mailchimp or SendGrid ,here are some PROS and CONS

**Mailchimp**

**PROS**

- Free appexchange on the salesforce

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3byfEAB

- Lightning ready now so you dont have to worry in future if you upgrade to lightning design
- [Pricing seems to be fair](http://mailchimp.com/pricing/) for mailchimp service
- The salesforce appexchange is free of cost

**CONS**

The app has decent 3.0 rating on appexchange

**SendGrid**

**PROS**

There is a privately listed app on the appexchange

- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA
- Excellent rating on appexchange

**CONS**

- No official app yet on the appexchange from the SendGrid and the app on the appexchange is from third party company called Manasa
- Apart from service you will also end up paying 20USD for one user per month .

Using appexchange will be quick win if you dont have enough devs to work on integrations and visualforce else you absolutely dont need any of those and can build your custom integrations .Both these services provides nice API .On the downside apps on appexchange are really secure and building a secure app will involve some resource and expense

Comment: I was planning on going the route of building direct integrations with them. Doing API calls.